# When using chai-as-promised can you get a line number w/ the failed assertion?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

Using mocha + chai, when an AssertionError is thrown, I see this

```
AssertionError: expected 2 to equal 4
      + expected - actual

      -2
      +4

    at Context.<anonymous> (test/sync.coffee:116:18)
```

When using chai-as-promised I see this

```
1) Syncing Non-bare (empty staging area) to bare should sync all files:

      AssertionError: expected 2 to equal 3
      + expected - actual

      -2
      +3
```

Is there a simple way to get the line number when using chai-as-promised?

Full reproduction repo here
https://github.com/rissem/chai-as-promised-stack-trace

`npm install`

`npm test`

Comment: Can you show your test/spec?